# React App: Creating new User and Authentication Issue with the old one

Tags: reactjs, debugging, firebase-authentication, react-hook-form, state-management

**Issue:**
After successfully creating a new user using the UserForm component, the user's authentication state changes automatically to the newly created user. This behavior is unexpected and leads to change the current user to the one just created.

**Desired Outcome:**
I would like to understand why the authentication state is changing automatically after creating a new user using the UserForm component. I want to ensure that the authentication state remains unaffected by the user creation process and that the user remains logged in with the same credentials they used during login, regardless of any user creation activity.

**Relevant Code:**
the userForm component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import {
  Alert,
  Button,
  CircularProgress,
  MenuItem,
  Snackbar,
  Stack,
  TextField,
  Backdrop,
  AlertTitle,
} from "@mui/material";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { auth, db } from "../../../firebase";
import { doc, serverTimestamp, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import Header from "../../../components/Header";
import { textFields, data } from "./data";

const UserForm = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selectedRole, setSelectedRole] = useState("HR");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    setValue,
  } = useForm();

  const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === "clickaway") {
      return;
    }

    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const onSubmit = async (formData) => {
    setLoading(true);

    try {
      const { email, password, ...userData } = formData;

      // Create user with email and password
      const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password, {
        forceSignIn: false,
      });

      // Store user data in Firestore, including selected role
      await setDoc(doc(db, "users", res.user.uid), {
        email,
        ...userData,
        role: selectedRole, // Include selected role
        timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
      });

      handleClick();

      setIsError(false);
      setError("");
      // Clear form fields after submission
      Object.keys(formData).forEach((field) => {
        setValue(field, "");
      });
    } catch (err) {
      setIsError(true);
      setError(err.message);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false); // Stop loading
    }
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <Header title="CREATE USER" subTitle="Create a New User Profile" />

      <Box
        onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        component="form"
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          gap: 3,
        }}
        noValidate
        autoComplete="off"
      >
        <Stack sx={{ gap: 2 }} direction={"row"}>
          {textFields.slice(0, 2).map((field) => (
            <TextField
              key={field.name}
              {...register(field.name, { required: true, minLength: 3 })}
              error={Boolean(errors[field.errorKey])}
              helperText={
                Boolean(errors[field.errorKey]) ? field.helperText : null
              }
              label={field.label}
              variant="filled"
              sx={{ flex: 1 }}
            />
          ))}
        </Stack>

        {textFields.slice(2).map((field) => (
          <TextField
            key={field.name}
            {...register(field.name, {
              required: true,
              pattern: field.pattern, // Set the pattern here
            })}
            error={Boolean(errors[field.errorKey])}
            helperText={
              Boolean(errors[field.errorKey]) ? field.helperText : null
            }
            label={field.label}
            variant="filled"
            type={field.type || "text"}
          />
        ))}

        <TextField
          variant="filled"
          id="role"
          select
          label="Role"
          defaultValue="HR"
          value={selectedRole} // Set the selected value
          onChange={(event) => setSelectedRole(event.target.value)} // Update selected role
        >
          {data.map((option) => (
            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </TextField>

        {isError && (
          <Alert severity="error">
            <AlertTitle>Error</AlertTitle>
            their is an error: {error}
          </Alert>
        )}

        <Box sx={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            sx={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}
            variant="contained"
          >
            Create New User
          </Button>

          <Snackbar
            anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "top", horizontal: "right" }}
            open={open}
            autoHideDuration={3000}
            onClose={handleClose}
          >
            <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="info" sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
              Account created successfully
            </Alert>
          </Snackbar>
        </Box>
      </Box>
      <Backdrop
        sx={{ color: "#fff", zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.drawer + 1 }}
        open={loading}
      >
        <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
      </Backdrop>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default UserForm;
```

the userAuthContext:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signOut,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../firebase";

const userAuthContext = createContext();

export function UserAuthContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  function logIn(email, password) {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }
  function logOut() {
    return signOut(auth);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentuser) => {
      setUser(currentuser);
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <userAuthContext.Provider value={{ user, logIn, logOut }}>
      {children}
    </userAuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useUserAuth() {
  return useContext(userAuthContext);
}
```

the App component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home/Home_Page";
import OperaForm from "./pages/Forms/Opera_Form/Opera_Form";
import UserForm from "./pages/Forms/User_Form/User_Form";
import Login from "./pages/Login/Login_Page";
import Requests from "./pages/Requests/Requests";
import EmployeesPage from "./pages/EmployeesList/Employees_Page";
import { UserAuthContextProvider } from "./context/UserAuthContext";
import ProtectedRoute from "./pages/Protected_Route";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <UserAuthContextProvider>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <ProtectedRoute>
              <Home />
            </ProtectedRoute>
          }
        >
          <Route path="/employeesList" element={<EmployeesPage />} />
          <Route path="/operaForm" element={<OperaForm />} />
          <Route path="/userForm" element={<UserForm />} />
          <Route path="/requests" element={<Requests />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      </Routes>
    </UserAuthContextProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I tried to change:

```
const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
```

to

```
const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password, {
        forceSignIn: false,
      });
```

but it did not work!